# How to get a remote desktop / X11 with ubuntu 10.04 LTS from mac os x?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, remote, x11

I am running Snow Leopard OS X 10.6 and I have X11 installed. I also have ubuntu 10.04 LTS running on a remote machine. I have root privileges. So far I haven't really installed anything besides the operating system. This was done in an amazon aws type of way.

I see people talking about getting gnome or a "remote desktop" type of thing working, but I'm not sure how to go about this. I connected and then typed in gnome-session but nothing happened. Maybe I don't have that thing installed yet? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Also, is it possible to just start an X11 session with a single app, like notepad or a file and folder browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "*Also, is it possible to just start an X11 session with a single app,
>   like notepad or a file and folder browser?*"

Use X forwarding with SSH to forward the app that you wish to run locally; Replace *gnome-terminal* in the example below with the name of your remote app.

```
ssh -X user@host gnome-terminal
```

Comment: bash: gnome-terminal: command not found - how do I get that installed?

Comment: Use `apt-get` or whatnot.

Comment: using rdesktop is also a possibility, but not sure it'll work on macOs...

Answer (score 2):

apt-get install xrdp
use rdp client on the Mac

Answer (score 2):

run **vncserver** from the linux box, and then connect to it with a vnc client like **Chicken of the VNC** for Mac